# How to declare variables for another function without passing it as argument of other function?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how can i do it?

e.g.

```
function get() {
   alert(s);
}
function declare() {
   var s = "Blah";
   get();
}
```

But I get that `s is not defined`.

I know we can do by passing it as argument and also setting it as global variable but how without both of them?

Comment: closures ! for the good of mankind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a closure:

```
function declare() {
   var s = "Blah";
   function get() {
      alert(s);
   }
   get();
}
```

Comment: I know about closures but that `get()` is just assumed function for example. But in my case it is load event.

Comment: Well, I think I answered the question that you asked.  Maybe you'd like to try a new post with your actual problem?

Comment: ahh man got it to work thanks. Didn't realized that it can be done through some mess with closures.

Comment: Just to clarify its the scope of the variable that this depends on and more information about that can be found here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope